# Rspec command to skip view specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

When we `rspec` command it runs all of the specs. I do not want to run view specs.

Is there way to `disable/skip` view specs??

Other than making those specs `pending`..

Comment: why can't you just disable views spec in your config file and in that way it will not generate views specs

Comment: Are you using rails generator for generating model / controller / views ?

Comment: I have disabled generation the view spec from `application.rb`. Wanted to know if there is a way to `not run` view spec when we use `rspec` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try something like this -

Use an `--exclude-pattern`

```
rspec --exclude-pattern "spec/views/**/*_spec.rb"
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-3/docs/configuration/exclude-pattern

Comment: this do not works when views has another folder in it